# Going from $\sum_{x=r}^\infty (x-r) f(x)$ to $ -(r-\lambda)(1-F(r)) + \lambda f(r)$

Tags: probability-theory

$$\sum_{x=r}^\infty (x-r) f(x)$$ is the loss function for a Poisson distribution, where $f(x)$ represents the PMF of the Poisson distribution, equal to:
$$\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!}$$

I was looking for a closed form of this loss function and in a book, I found the following:

$$ -(r-\lambda)(1-F(r)) + \lambda f(r) $$, where $F(r)$ is the CDF, equal to: $$\sum_{x=0}^r \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{x!} $$

But I get stuck on deriving it when I divide  $\sum_{x=r}^\infty (x-r) f(x)$ up in two parts:

$$-r\sum_{x=r}^\infty f(x)$$ and $$\sum_{x=r}^\infty x f(x)$$

The first part is $-r(1-F(r))$, but then I'm left with

$$\sum_{x=r}^\infty x f(x)$$, where I know that $$\lambda = \sum_{x=0}^\infty x f(x)$$, but I don't see how to go further...

Has anyone an idea to go from here to eventually show that:

$$ \sum_{x=r}^\infty (x-r) f(x) = -(r-\lambda)(1-F(r)) + \lambda f(r) $$ ?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINTS...

There are two issues here:

1: You have written "the first part is $-r(1-F(r))$" but this is wrong: since the sum starts at $x=r$, it should be $$-r(1-F(r-1)).$$

2: To evaluate $\sum_{x=r}^\infty x f(x)$ you will need to rewrite this as $$\sum_{x=r}^\infty\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{(x-1)!}$$
$$=\sum_{\color{red}{x=1}}^\infty\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{(x-1)!}-\sum_{\color{red}{x=1}}^{\color{red}{r-1}}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x}{(x-1)!}$$

Now re-index the sums:

$$=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{j+1}}{j!}-\sum_{j=0}^{r-2}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{j+1}}{j!}$$

Now extract the factor $\lambda$ and the second term is $\color{green}{F(r-2)}$ so use $F(r)=F(r-1)+f(r)$ etc.

I hope this helps. I assume you would prefer to figure this out yourself now.

Comment: Do you mean re-indexing the sums to $0$ and $\infty$ ?

Comment: yes, substitute $j=x-1$

Comment: please see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks again! If I work it out, I get $\lambda 1 -\lambda(F(r)-f(r))$, which then becomes  $\lambda(1-F(r))+\lambda f(r)$. But the only way I come to the expression $-(r-\lambda)(1-F(r)) + \lambda f(r)$ is that the first part is equal to $-r(1-F(r))$. So what am I missing?

Comment: sorry my mistake - please see the edit in green

Comment: let me know if you want me to post the full solution

Comment: Indeed curious to your solution, as I keep ending up with $-(r-\lambda)(1-F(r))+\lambda f(r) + rf(r)+\lambda f(r-1)$

Comment: It should be $−(r−λ)(1−F(r))+λf(r)-rf(r)+λf(r−1)$ and the last two terms cancel out because they are equal (check the formula for $f(r)$)